# call a method from another file in ruby

Tags: ruby

Hello I'm new to programming and I started with ruby. I'm trying to do my first program. I found online this code that generate a dice roll

```
class Die
  def initialize(sides)
    @sides = sides
  end

  def generate_die_roll
    rand(@sides) + 1
  end

  def roll(number=1)
    roll_array = []
    number.times do
      roll_array << generate_die_roll
    end
    total = 0
    roll_array.each do |roll|
      new_total = total + roll
      total = new_total
    end
   total
  end
end
```

and I would like to use in they way that if the number generated is inferior o equal to another print something otherwise something else.
It's probably very easy but i'm trying in every way and now I will need some help please.
that's my code:

```
require "./newdado.rb"
energia_vitale = 30
puts "Lancia un dado scrivendo (D) da sommare alla tua Energia Vitale iniziale di #{energia_vitale} punti"
scelta = gets.chomp

case scelta
when "D"

SIX_SIDED_DIE = "#{Die.new(6)}"
  values = Array[]
values.push(SIX_SIDED_DIE.roll)
  puts values
if values < 2
  puts "c"
else puts "b"
end
end
```

when I run it i receive this error
*C:/Users/fix/workspace/D&D Ruby/energia vitale.rb:11:in `<main>': undefined method`roll' for "#":String (NoMethodError)*

Sorry to bother the community with this beginner problem

Answer (score 1):

Why as string?

this line

```
SIX_SIDED_DIE = "#{Die.new(6)}"`
```

should be something like

```
die = Die.new(6)
```

then you can do `die.roll`

Comment: Thank you so much I I thought was necessary for calling a class in another file but now i realized that I probably need to study more and more.